# Trying to fetch child collection of parent document

Tags: javascript, ionic3, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I'm using AngularFire2 in an Ionic 3 application to fetch data from an Angular Firestore Database. In the database, I have a '/Products/' collection, each document of which has a '/Versions/' child collection:

[image]

In my application I have already fetched the Product (cast to a DTO) and wanted to fetch it's child versions. I've been trying different methods but can't seem to figure out how to refer to the child.

This is the code I'm using the fetch the Products:

```
this.fireStore.collection('/Products/', i => i.orderBy('Title'));
```

Once I have a `Product` object, how do I fetch it's versions?

EDIT: Someone asked for what code I have so far, but as you can see I'm missing the link between 'product' and the related versions:

```
public getVersionsForProduct(product: Product) : AngularFirestoreCollection<Version>{
    var vers = this.fireStore.collection<Version>('/Version/');
    return vers;
  }
```

Comment: can you share full code you have so far?

Comment: I'm not familiar with AngularFire.  However, I may be able to give you some pointers.  When you select a product that you want to fetch the versions for, pass its `ref` to your `getVersionsForProduct` function and then extend that to get the `versions` collection... with the web SDK, this would be `product.collection('Versions').get()`.  Hopefully, you can translate to AngularFire (which I need to learn.  Sorry if my comment isn't correct on this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without seeing all your relevant code it's hard to say, but you can get subcollections like this:

```
public getVersionsForProduct(product: Product) : AngularFirestoreCollection<Version> {

    const vers = this.fireStore.collection('Products').doc(product.id).collection<Version>('Versions'); 
    return vers;
  }
```